# What is an ideal login workflow along with Facebook's OAuth2?

Tags: angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

So today, I tried playing with Facebook's OAuth2 in my AngularJS application. I was able to make an activity work by clicking a Like button in my app. I'm also able to check if I'm logged in to Facebook using FB.getLoginStatus(). So my question is, if we currently have a login page, what is the ideal user experience when combining it with Facebook?

1. Do you display Facebook login page then goes back to your original login(this is what is happening on my application right now)
2. Do you display Facebook login page then once you've been logged in, bypass your original login page and allow the app to bring you directly to the main application. But how do I find out the facebook username that was used to log in?
3. any more ideas?